# NSolve not solving within Table

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I would like to solve an equation for different parameter values, thus, I used Table[] to create an array of solutions. For some parameter combinations {k,A} NSolve does not give an answer, but when I call NSolve outside of Table with the same parameters, it actually works. Below is a minimal example of this behaviour - any ideas where this comes from are much appreciated :-). FYI I am using Mathematica 13.0 MacOS.

```
function[k_, A_, u1_, u2_] := (1 + Tanh[k (u1 - 2 A u2)])/2 - u1
results[k_, A_] := NSolve[function[k, A, u1, u2] == 0 && function[k, A, u2, u1] == 0 && 0 <= u1 <= 1 &&0 <= u2 <= 1, {u1, u2}]
{results[0.2, 2.2], results[0.2, 2.3], results[0.2, 2.4]}
Table[results[0.2, b], {b , 2.2, 2.4, 0.1}]
```

Follow up:
Here are some more variations. It seems there is a difference between numbers explicitly typed in and those created automatically. When I type all numbers in Table, it works, but when I create a list of numbers with Range and use that in Table, it does not work anymore...

```
Table[results[0.2, b], {b, {2.2, 2.3, 2.4}}] // Quiet
values = Range[2.2, 2.4, 0.1];
Table[results[0.2, b], {b, values}] // Quiet
```

And similar issue with Map

```
Map[results[0.2, #] &, {2.2, 2.3, 2.4}] // Quiet
Map[results[0.2, #] &, values] // Quiet
```

Comment: `Table[results[0.2, b], {b, {2.2, 2.3, 2.4}}]`

Comment: Yes, that works, but for a large parameter search, I can not type all of them explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Another way is use `Rationalize` to the values `k` and `A`

```
function[k_, A_, u1_, u2_] := (1 + Tanh[k (u1 - 2 A u2)])/2 - u1;
results[k_, A_] := 
 NSolve[function[Rationalize@k, Rationalize@A, u1, u2] == 0 && 
   function[Rationalize@k, Rationalize@A, u2, u1] == 0 && 
   0 <= u1 <= 1 && 0 <= u2 <= 1, {u1, u2}]
values = Range[2.2, 2.4, 0.1];
Table[results[0.2, b], {b, values}]
Table[results[0.2, b], {b, 2.2, 2.4, .1}]
```

**Original**

Maybe use exact number by `Rationalize`

```
values = Range[2.2, 2.4, 0.1] // Rationalize;
Table[results[0.2, b], {b, values}]
```

Comment: Great, that seems to work - thanks a lot @cvgmt!

Comment: @Tim  We can use `Rationalize` to `k` and `A` then avoid all the warning.

Answer (score 3):

Try `Map` (don't know why `Table` doesn't work)

```
Map[results[0.2, #] &, { 2.2, 2.4, 0.1}] // Quiet
(*{{{u1 -> 0.375147, u2 -> 0.375147}}, 
{{u1 -> 0.364816,u2 -> 0.364816}}, 
{{u1 -> 0.54336, u2 -> 0.54336}}}*)
```

**Edit**
I still do not understand why `NSolve` (numerical solver!)  only evaluates with `Rationalize`!

`NMinimize` solves without this limitation:

```
res[k_, A_] := 
NMinimize[{1, function[k, A, u1, u2] == 0,function[k, A, u2, u1]== 0, 0 <= u1 <= 1, 0 <= u2 <= 1}, {u1, u2}] [[2]]

Table[res[0.2, b], {b, {2.2, 2.4, .1}}]
(*{{u1 -> 0.375147, u2 -> 0.375147}, {u1 -> 0.364816,u2 -> 0.364816}, {u1 -> 0.54336, u2 -> 0.54336}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it does not solve the issue! Here, you use 0.1 as an input value, not 2.2, 2.3, 2.4. like in Table. It seems to me there is a difference between numbers explicitly typed in and those generated automatically. I added some more variations in my questions to show this. When you explicitly write all numbers in Table it works, but when I create a list of numbers with Range and use that list in Table, it does not work..